# How do you define an xgboost model where the predicted value is based on previous iterations?

Tags: r, xgboost

I've built the following model, but can't work out how to implement it in xgboost.

I'm trying to approximate probabilities within a given portfolio using an existing spreadsheet as the basis (initial y_test values).

Assuming I have split my dataset into data tables train_db and test_db:

```
oos_error <- Inf

repeat {
    rf <- 
        train(
            train_dt[, .(<x values>)],
            train_dt[, y / y_test],
            weights = train_dt$WEIGHTS,
            preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
            method = "rpart2",
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(maxdepth = 2)
        )
    
    train_dt[, y_test := 0.99 * y_test + 0.01 * y_test * predict(rf, newdata = train_dt)]
    test_dt[, y_test := 0.99 * y_test + 0.01 * y_test * predict(rf, newdata = test_dt)]
    
    oos_error_prev <- oos_error
    oos_error <- test_dt[, LOSS_FUNCTION(.)] ## Residual squared error
    
    if (oos_error > oos_error_prev) {
        break()
    }
}
```

When trying to construct my train_dt xgb.DMatrix input, I'm not sure what to put as the input, since what is trying to be predicted is based on the previous input.